# Какая разница между словами ПРЕКЛОНЯТЬСЯ И ПРИКЛОНЯТЬСЯ?

Tags: орфография, значение-слов, приставка

Какая разница между словами ПРЕКЛОНЯТЬСЯ И ПРИКЛОНЯТЬСЯ? Случаи использования этих слов.

Comment: Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

===

Ты помнишь наши встречи летом

Меж лепестков, меж лепестков?

Где трепетал, пронизан светом,

Кудряволиственный покров?

Ты помнишь, раздвигая травы,

Мы опускались у куста?

И были взоры так лукавы,

И так застенчивы уста.

К стволу развесистого дуба

Затылком приклонялась ты.

И жадно я впивался в губы ―

Две влажно-алые черты. 

=

[В. В. Гофман. Меж лепестков (1903-1904)] 

==========

Как не пожалеть о нем о строгом,

Но вершившем справедливый суд.

Раньше-то его считали богом,

Преклонялись, а теперь клянут. 

=

[Д. Самойлов. Старик и домовой (1989)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Преклоняться** перед кем? чем? (**высокое**) - относиться с большим уважением, преклоняться перед подвигом.

**Приклониться** к чему? - (**разговорное**) пригнуться, ветка приклонилась к земле.

Answer (score 1):

> ПРЕКЛОНИТЬ - Высок. Наклонить, опустить вниз, нагнуть. Все почтительно преклонили головы. П. знамёна. Преклонить колена (колени) (опуститься, стать на колени).
>
> ПРИКЛОНИТЬ - Слегка склонить. П. ветку черёмухи. П. к лицу георгин. П. голову куда-л., где-л., к кому-л. (также: разг.; найти приют, место, где жить).