# Можно ли использовать слово "преклоняться" с дательным падежом?

Tags: падежи

Можно ли сказать "преклоняться мне" вместо "преклоняться передо мной"?

Предусматривает ли глагол "преклоняться" дательный падеж после себя?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно только *преклониться* ***перед***

Толковый словарь Ожегова: 
ПРЕКЛОНИ́ТЬСЯ, -ню́сь, -ни́шься; сов., перед кем-чем (высок.). Почувствовать глубокое уважение, восхищение. П. перед героическим подвигом.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли использовать слово “преклоняться” с дательным падежом?

.

Можно. Но только при воспроизведении старых текстов.

Глагол ***преклоняться*** имел в русском языке несколько значений.

**В современном русском используется только переносное его значение:** "испытывать, чувствовать преклонение перед кем-, чем-л." В этом значении ***преклоняться*** требует от сочетающегося с ним существительного творительного падежа с предлогом  ***перед/пред/предо***). Пример:

*Я знал Таню ещё в ту пору,  когда она была глупенькой девчонкой, принимала любое мое слово на веру, **преклонялась предо** мной* (Колесников. Право выбора).

**В другом своём значении** ("наклоняться, нагибаться; приклоняться; склоняться, сгибаться в поклоне"), ныне устаревшем,  глагол ***преклоняться***  мог употребляться и с винительным (с предлогом ***на***), и с дательным  (с предлогом ***к/ко***), и с творительным (с предлогом ***перед***) падежом существительного.

Примеры:

*[Манефа] села на свое игуменское место, **преклонясь на** посох, окрашенный прозеленью с золотыми разводами* (Мельников-Печерский. В лесах).

*Как она любила! Как нежно преклонясь ко мне Она в пустынной тишине Часы ночные проводила!* (Пушкин. Цыганы).

*Не раз случалось, что молился при нем отец на пороге кумирни; он **преклонялся перед** лежачей деревянной статуей, бормоча ее заповеди, поднимая соединенные ладони ко лбу, а потом клал на жертвенник самую мелкую и старую из своих тяжко заработанных монет* (И. А. Бунин. Братья).

**А вот в третьем значении** — "покоряться, подчиняться кому-л., признавать чью-л. власть над собой" — глагол ***преклоняться*** мог употребляться с дательным падежом и в беспредложной конструкции. Пример:

*Бунтовщики кричали гарнизону, что войска правительства разбиты, что Оренбург, Уфа и Казань уже **преклонились самозванцу**, что он скоро придет к Яицкому городку и что тогда уже пощады не будет* (А. С. Пушкин. История Пугачева).

В настоящее время глагол ***преклоняться***  в таком значении **не употребляется.**

Comment: 2-e значение - как совр. приклониться? см: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49971/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%AF-%D0%98-%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%AF

Comment: "в **таком** значении не употребляется". В каком? Может, в **таких** (2-м и 3-м)?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **преклоняться передо мной.**

**ПРЕКЛОНИТЬСЯ**, св. Высок. 1. **Склониться, согнуться в поклоне;** опуститься на колени. Богомольцы низко преклонились **перед** игуменом. П. перед могилой. 2. **Почувствовать глубокое уважение,** благоговение, восхищение; выразить чувство преклонения (2 зн.). П. перед подвигом солдата. Мне хочется п. перед ней за её самоотверженность.

Итак, **прямое значение глагола** ― это склониться в поклоне **перед предметом  или лицом (Т.п.)** (указывается место).

Сравнить:  **ПОКЛОНИТЬСЯ** (кому-чему). Сделать поклон  кому-л. в знак приветствия, почтения, благодарности.

В этом случае дательный падеж указывает на лицо, **к которому** (Д.п.) обращен поклон как знак приветствия или уважения.

Answer (score -1):

Словарь Ушакова:

1. несовер. к преклониться. «Я преклоняюсь перед тобою». А.Тургенев.

Гугл-книги также не согласны с вашим первым вариантом.

Answer (score -1):

"Преклоняться пред" и "преклоняться перед" - из-за разных предлогов, разные вещи.
Преклонение - это не только телесное действие (поклон), но ещё и действие чувств - чествование, признательность, уважение, отдавать должное.

Преклоняться перед - что это значит: идёт очередь преклоняющихся и кто-то в этой очереди стоит прежде кого-то, будет следующим на преклонение?

Предлог "перед" употребляется в том случае, когда необходимо дать понять о положении, в котором одно понятие находится в зависимости от другого понятия. Например: 1) "стоит перед нами" (положение от лица людей, в поле зрения которых находится некое понятие); 2) "стою перед ними" (положение от лица человека, который находится в поле зрения других людей). Предлог "пред" употребляется в том случае, когда необходимо дать понять о последовательности или о первоначальности. Например: 1) "стоит пред нами" (раньше нас в очереди; сначала идёт он, потом мы); 2) "стою пред ними" (стою раньше их в очереди).
Короче: пред - это прежде, а перед - на виду.

Преклоняться мне: 1) придётся преклониться (лично мне придется; подобно: отдуваться мне за вас); 2) (с предлогом "пред") мой черёд на преклонение (предстать пред кем-то воочию). 3) (с предлогом "перед") со временем кто-то будет преклоняться передо мной (отдавать должное моим заслугам).